# How to obtain a key pressed code in java AWT using keyEventDispatcher

Tags: java, awt

Is it possible to obtain the simple key code of a pressed key using the KeyEventDispatcher? I am attempting to intercept the pressed keys, concatenate them into a string, and display them in an AWT TextArea (a simple text editor). The issue is that the KeyEventDispatcher returns three integer numbers in three lines. Generally speaking, the code in the body of the dispatcher is executed three times after any key is pressed, and I do not know why. The first line is the number of the key code, the second is 0, and the third is the same code as in the first one. If I press any function key, there are only two identical numbers.

```
public class KeyEventInterceptionExample {
    private static StringBuilder keyBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    private static TextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Frame frame = new Frame("Key Event Interception Example");

            textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.setBounds(20, 30, 300, 150);

            MyKeyEventDispatcher keyEventDispatcher = new MyKeyEventDispatcher();
                  KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(keyEventDispatcher);

            frame.add(textArea);

            frame.setSize(350, 220);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

         
        });
    }

    static class MyKeyEventDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

            int cCode = e.getKeyCode());
            // i decide what the char will be displayed
            textArea.append(myChar);


           
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to obtain the simple integer code of the pressed key. I will decide what to display and add it to the TextArea. Additionally, how can I recognize which keys are pressed simultaneously?

Comment: You shouldn't be using AWT for visual components at all. It's been obsolete for a long time. You should be using Swing with a `KeyListener`. Also, [avoid using null layouts](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: *I am attempting to intercept the pressed keys, concatenate them into a string, and display them in an AWT TextArea (a simple text editor).* - so why are you making the TextArea non-editable? The point of using a TextArea is that it already supports the typing of text into the text area.

Comment: i want to process input keys outside of any component, e.g. create or editing string and only then deliver it to the selected component (there will by a few of them); i want the input processing mechanism be independet from any component

Comment: as i noticed key event dispatcher is used by swing as well to intercept input keys globally, so what is wrong with my code?

Comment: *The issue is that the KeyEventDispatcher returns three integer numbers in three lines.* - keyPressed, keyTyped and keyReleased events are generated. *create or editing string* - then create a popup "text field". When the user is finished typing the text you move the text to the selected component. This sounds like a poor design. How does the user know that if they just start typing randomly on the frame that the text will be captured? This is why Swing components have the concept of "focus", so the user knows which component will receive the text.